# Best jQuery method for auto adding text

Tags: jquery, css

I'm still learning jQuery and have been playing with something as an exercise.  I have this working:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>New Site</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>    
<body>    
<ul class="accmenu">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a><span> +</span>
<ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1 a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">item 1 b</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a><span> +</span>
<ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">item 3c</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(".accmenu li ul").hide();
$( document ).ready(function() {

$(".accmenu li").toggle(function(){
//    $(".accmenu li ul").slideDown();
    $(this).children("ul").slideDown(); 
    $(this).children("span").html( " -" );
},function(){
//    $(".accmenu li ul").slideUp();
    $(this).children("ul").slideUp();   
    $(this).children("span").html( " +" );  
});

});    
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

My question is this at the end of each parent I have manually added:

```
<span> +</span>
```

Is there a plausable method for making this, and the corresponding  - happen autoamtically via jQuery?  Without writing the actual span into the code?

Basically I want jQuery to find every li with ul under it and at the end of the text in the li to add " +" or " -" depending on whether its collapsed or not.

I looked at the possibility for jQuery's append but I dont want to keep adding...basically I want the +/- to happen automatically and to toggle as the menu slides up/down.

Comment: Although you haven't tagged CSS, this is a great opportunity to toggle classes with jQuery and give each class a different text `content`.

Comment: And as a side note, the toggle() event was removed from jQuery after 1.8.

Comment: I've tagged CSS now.  Once I get a better handle on how to handle the +/- I will work on a rewrite to remove .toggle...thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Was `toggle` ever actually an event. I think it was just a function that fired captured `onclick` in the background.

Comment: If you don't want to learn anything (other than how to use jQueryUI, that is), you could look at the [Menu](http://jqueryui.com/menu/) plugin.

Comment: I'd actually like to dissect to to figure it out. :-)  I'm just kinda stuck.  I will look at that too though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually avoid checking for children `ul` by adding `:before` pseudo element to the ul itself. http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/8v9Bw/

CSS

```
/*hide content and disc*/
.accmenu > li {
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style-type: none;
}

/*moves +/- to the left of the link*/
.accmenu > li > a {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}

/*closed menu item*/
.accmenu > li > ul:before {
    content: '+';
}

/*opened menu item*/    
.accmenu > li.active > ul:before {
    content: '\2013';
}

/*height animation effect !requires prefixes and modern browsers.*/    
.accmenu > li > ul {    
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out;
}

.accmenu > li.active > ul {    
    max-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I've played with what has been posted so far and I think this method will best suit my ultimate goal with it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, use CSS to add the plus sign and use Javascript to toggle the class.

Try this:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6tn5Q/2/)

```
ul {
width: 200px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
}

ul li {
min-height: 0;
}

ul li.active {
min-height: 30px;
}

ul li:after {
content: "+";
float: right;
}

ul li.active:after {
content: '-';
}


<ul>
<li>Parent 1</li>
<li>Parent 2</li>
</ul>

$('li').click(function () {
$(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: shouldn't you test if the parent have child?

Comment: Yes.. And you should also add a test to see if other elements have been expanded and collapse them, if you do not want more than one to be visible, but this is just to show how he can add the +/- signs without having to add actual HTML content.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use of `toggleClass()` function.

Please add below in your code:

JQuery

```
$('a').click(function(){debugger;
$(this).toggleClass("pclass nclass" )
});
```

CSS

```
.pclass:after{
    content: "+";
} 

.nclass:after{
    content: "-"
}
```

Created **[fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/NTLvA/1/)**